# Create table in C# using mySQL and MariaDB

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb

A week ago, I've asked, how to create a database in MariaDB with a C#-program and then it worked.

So, I thought, it wouldn't be that difficult, to create some other SQL-commands, but it didn't work.

[image: Exception thrown]

To the code: I've made a constructor, which create a database in MariaDB, which worked. So I've created a method, which should use the database and create a table with the statements. This didn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace mySqlCsPrototype3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            route rot = new route();
            rot.useDBCreateTable();
            Console.Read();
        }


    }
    public class route
    {
        public route()
        {
            string verbindung = "server=localhost;database=example_bankdb;uid=root;password=";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(verbindung);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            string s0;

            try
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`;";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, dbConn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbConn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Verbindung wird hergestellt");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Die Verbindung kann nicht hergestellt werden");
            }

        }

        public void useDBCreateTable()
        {
            string verbindung = "server=localhost;database=example_bankdb;uid=root;password=";
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(verbindung);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            string s0;
            try
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                s0 = "USE 'mydb'; CREATE TABLE 'user' IF NOT EXISTS('userID' INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,'name' varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('userID'));";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, dbConn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                dbConn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Verbindung wird hergestellt");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Die Verbindung kann nicht hergestellt werden");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Example code

So, I hope, you can help me.

Greetings, Pilaucho

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "didn't work" in code without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? I notice you are suppressing your exceptions, so maybe start by adding some code to log the actual error message and not just a random phrase you invented.

Comment: It hasn't thrown an error message, it couldn't execute the query and I don't know why.

Comment: _"It hasn't thrown an error message"_ ...yes it has. According to your screenshot, it outputs `Die Verbindung kann nicht hergestellt werden` on the second line. This means it entered the second `catch` block inside the (`useDBCreateTable` method). The fact you don't get an actual exception message is because, as I mentioned above, you are deliberately suppressing the real exception messages! This is an anti-pattern, and will leave you unable to ever debug your code.

Comment: At the very least you should be writing (`catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Die Verbindung kann nicht hergestellt werden"); Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }` to get minimal information. Obviously for real-life use you should log that data to the event log or to a file, instead of showing it on screen. But for this purpose it should be better.

Comment: One other thing...you wrote `s0 = "USE 'mydb'; CREATE TABLE 'user'`...but just above that, you wrote `string verbindung = "server=localhost;database=example_bankdb;`.... If you want to use `mydb` for the query, then why not just set that in the connection string?? `string verbindung = "server=localhost;database=mydb;`. The the query itself can be just `s0 = "CREATE TABLE` ...etc. I suspect one issue you could be having is you can't execute more than one statement at once via ADO.NET

Comment: And a third thing...you are not disposing of your connection objects, you just leave them open (whether or not an error occurs). You should be making use of `using { ... }` blocks to ensure .NET automatically disposes of the connection when it's finished. This is commonly-known best practice.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I found my mistake, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I found the mistake, I've made.
In C#, the names of a database or a table must be in those brickets[``].

```
s0 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user`(`userID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`userID`));";
```

Thanks for your attention and your nerves.

Comment: True, but it's not just in C#. That's standard MySQL syntax. It would have failed if you ran it directly in mysql as well. Hopefully at least you've learned to log your exceptions in C# now though :-)

Comment: P.S. those ` brackets are known as "backticks"